# Two method error in .asmx web service

Tags: web-services, asmx, ado.net-entity-data-model

I developed a web service and i  write with c#. My web service is an asmx. But in my service i have 2 method. first one is helloworld(),second method is insert_Data. All of them is webmethod. But if i want to write third method , my application give me an error. My application couldn't see any method like insert_Data or helloworld or new method is refresh.

I used to Ado.net entity data model,and can't find anything about this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Well, "what error" and "caused by what code"? Adding a 3rd method didn't break it. *Incorrect* code when adding a 3rd method might have.

Comment: I think there is no problem in my [webmethod] because i build and start web service and three method appears to me and if i invoke anyone,method gives me a correct xml answer.

Comment: My problem is if a want to call method in my application, there isn't anymethod appears to me.